# moving maximum in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

how can i implement a moving maximum in postgresql?

For example, if we have a table ordered by b desc:

```
a   b
1   5
2   4
1   2
6   2
```

I would like to have a third column tracking the maximum value of a so far:

```
max_a_sofar
1
2
2
6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `max` window function.

```
select a,b,max(a) over(order by b desc,a) as running_a_max
from t
```